# How to get the scene dock in xcode 4.6 to display the view controller name?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am just getting started with xcode 4.6 and iOS dev in general.

I created a single view iOS app and I can see the scene dock,but am not able to see view controller name on the scene dock while viewing the mainstoryboard in xcode. Instead I see the view controller, first responder and responder icons on it. How do I get the view controller name to appear.

You can see the screenshot at http://i49.tinypic.com/15n64vt.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the name is displayed when you select a different view controller in Interface Builder, but in your case you cannot do it since you are working with a single view controller.

Therefore I suggest you to use the document outline to show the name of your view controller. You can open it by clicking the rounded icon on the bottom left.

Comment: Sweet. Is that same reason why the appdelegate files are named AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m instead of <ProjectName>AppDelegate.h and <ProjectName>AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Usually those files are named `<ClassPrefix>AppDelegate.h` and `<ClassPrefix>AppDelegate.m` but I don't see any correlation with this specific issue.

Comment: What i am seeing is that when you create a single view application in xcode, you dont have the classprefix

Comment: Oh I didn't pay attention to it. It maybe related, but I don't know why :)